# Objeto con X cantidad de propiedades no definidas

Tags: nodejs

Fronted: React
Backend: Node + Express
DB: MongoDB

Hola, lo que intento armar es que desde el frontend el usuario pueda crear un producto pero que el único campo definido de antemano para este producto sea su idproducto, luego, todos los demás campos los pueda "generar" el usuario. La idea seria que tenga un botón del tipo "Agregar campo" y que el sistema le pregunte si el campo es texto, numérico, booleano o fecha y que le permita darle un nombre y un valor.

```
[
  {
    "_id": "60212f11eba6c7e0639ea1d0",
    "nombre": "Producto 1",
    "costo": 100,
    "precio": 200,
    "marca": "HP"
  },
  {
    "_id": "60212f11eba6c7e0639ea1d0",
    "nombre": "Producto 2",
    "costo": 100,
    "precio": 200,
    "marca": "Lenovo",
    "modelo": "HR1"
  },
  {
    "_id": "60212f11eba6c7e0639ea1d0",
    "nombre": "Producto N",
    "propiedad_1": "valor_1",
    "propiedad_2": "valor_2",
    "propiedad_3": "valor_3",
    "propiedad_4": "valor_4",
    "propiedad_N": "valor_N"
  }
]
```

El objetivo es tener una especie de objeto genérico y que el usuario no tenga que definir de entrada la cantidad de campos que necesita.

Gracias!

Comment: ¿cuál es el problema?

Comment: Hola @PabloLozano! El problema es que no se me ocurre la forma de realizarlo. Lo que pense es crear dentro de un objeto definido una coleccion y que las propiedades que vaya generando el usuario se vayan guardando ahi, de esta manera tendria definido mi model. Que opinas?

Comment: Podrías tener una lista de objetos `{ key: "...", value: "..."}`

Comment: @PabloLozano El usuario tiene que tener la posiblidad de definir el tipo de dato (String, numeric, date o boolean)... Lo mejor seria dejar armado cuatro colecciones con esta posibilidad abierta verdad?

Comment: Puedes añadir un campo extra, indicando el tipo: `{ key: "today", value: 1612792424617, type:"date"}`

Comment: Excelente @PabloLozano muchas gracias, con esto me ayudaste mucho!

Answer (score 0):

No he trabajado con bases de datos no relacionales, pero he tenido que hacer algo parecido a lo que pedís con una base de datos relacional: *que un usuario pueda crear campos personalizados para un producto*.

Lo que yo hice fue crear una tabla para los campos personalizados del producto, con las siguientes propiedades:

- id: el id del row.
- nombre: el nombre que le pone el usuario al campo.
- valor: el valor del campo personalizado.
- tipo: booleano, texto, lista desplegable, etc.
- código del producto: el id del producto al cual corresponde este campo.

Por un lado tendrías tu tabla de productos, donde solo tendrías el id del producto y por el otro tendrías una tabla con los campos del producto, donde tendrías todos los campos de todos los productos, pero cada campo tendría como FK el id del producto al cual corresponde.

Buena suerte !

Comment: Hola! Es una buena opción, primero voy a probar la de colecciones y en caso de que no le encuentre la vuelta voy a probar esta opción también, Muchas gracias